# get frame from object in NSMutable array xcode

Tags: xcode, arrays, nsmutablearray, frame

the objective of this code is to automatically create an object and animate it to move across screen. once it reaches x at 120 then it is deleted. the problem I am facing is that i can not get the frame and there for the x value from the object in the array. here is my code, any suggestions?

```
- (void)AddRight{

Bullets= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(480, 180, 60, 55);
Bullets = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
Bullets.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Bullet.png"];
[self.view addSubview:Bullets];

[Bullets addObject:theBullet];
for (int x = 0; x < [Bullets count]; x++) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [theBullet setFrame:CGRectMake(265, 180, 60, 55)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

}
and the detection is here:

```
for (int x = 0; x < [Bullets count]; x++) {
        NSObject *bull = [[LeftBees objectAtIndex:x]];
       CGRect frame = bull.frame;
        if (frame.origin.x>120) {
            [bull removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

the "CGRect frame = referal.frame;" has ther error saying "Property frame is not part of NSObject"

Comment: Why class is referal? Is seems like it's an `NSObject`.

Comment: You really should learn naming conventions. This is very hard to read with variable and method names in uppercase.

Comment: ya thats not actually the names i used in my program, i just changed them to bullets to make more sence to people, guess that backfired but anyone have a solution?